# Java WebSockets on JBoss

Tags: java, websocket, jboss

I am using Spring MVC Rest API.I tried WebSockets on Tomcat Apache 7.64.Now we are planning to use JBoss EAP 6.4 as our server.I tried to use webSockets on it but it is not working.

I tried the following link:
https://github.com/tqvarnst/eap-wsdemo

Error is as follows:

```
12:40:27,081 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/wsdemo].[default]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000034: Cannot upgrade from HTTP/1.1 without IO events
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.sendUpgrade(Response.java:1370) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.upgrade(Request.java:3337) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.upgrade(RequestFacade.java:1062) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.UpgradeUtil.doUpgrade(UpgradeUtil.java:226) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:77) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

Any answers will be helpful.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016996/jboss-eap-6-3-beta-with-websocket-and-stockjs-stomp-js-using-spring-framework

Comment: I have the jboss-web.xml and have set enable websockets to true.But I am unable to configure the NIO connector using the provided script EAP_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --file=configure-http-connector.cli....Can you guide me with the same.Thanks

Comment: I have got the answer...in the standalone.xml the xml config file of the jboss server just replace line 
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/> 
with 
<connector name="http" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>